# Discritization Based on a Calculated Measure in Tabular Mode

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2012

I am currently trying to implement the following scenario on Tabular Mode SSAS, appreciate your support.

We have a fact table of Transactions that is the linked to the customer dimension, and we have a measure called Frequency that shows the number of times the user used his card during the selected period (The fact table is also linked to Date Dimension). What we need to do is create a dimension that would have the frequency groups as follows (For example, 1 to 5, 5 to 10 , 10 to 15 and 15 & Above). The problem here is that I am unable to link the Fact table to this dimension becuase the link between them would be a calculated measure.

Any thoughts?

Thanks and Best Regards

Omar Sultan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link the fact to a bucket dimension, you are going to have to specify the time granularity.  I would suggest that you decide one or more useful periods (day, week, month) and create a facts (or several) to bucket your data at the appropriate grain.

This solution will lose flexibility from your original request, as the user will not be able to dynamically select the time period for the bucket, however they will gain from being able to compare fixed time periods to identify trends over time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not be able to follow that approach, the requirement is for dynamic time periods and we will be using it with dynamic charts supporting drill down and drill through